# jQuery - sum every input value in a form

Tags: javascript, forms, input, sum

I'd like to count the sum of all the numeric values of a lot of input fields inside a form, every time one of the values changes.
I think this code is quite closer, but when I change twice the same input it is wrong.

```
tot = 0;
$('form#form-id :input').change(function(){
  $("form#form-id :input").each(function(){
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(tot);
});
```

This also seems to works well on jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/yq9zenaz/ but I get NaN on production.

Comment: Define the variable locally...

Comment: Maybe you could check the value before adding to make sure it's a number? `if(!isNaN($(this).val())) { //Your code }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Define the variable locally or else `global` value will be updated every time `change` handler is invoked.

```js
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function() {
  var tot = 0;
  $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function() {
    tot += Number($(this).val());
    // Could be written as
    // tot += +this.value;
  });
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="lines-form-1">
  <input type="number" name="i1">
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="i2">
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="i3">
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="i4">
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="i5">
  <br>

</form>
<div id="tot-qty">0</div>
```

### [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/yq9zenaz/3/)

Comment: But in this case, you can't access `tot` globally. I don't know if needed, but you cant. Just set `tot = 0;` every time `change` got tiggered, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Very precise, thanks. 
Andwhat if I have some default values on it?
https://jsfiddle.net/yq9zenaz/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/yq9zenaz/7/ Invoke `.change()` initially...

Answer (score 1):

Reset `tot` inside the callback, otherwise you will be continue adding numbers, but it's not the correct value.

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yq9zenaz/1/

```
var tot = 0;
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function(){
    tot = 0;
    $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function(){
        tot += Number($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(tot);
    $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

If you don't need `tot` to be accessible globally, just use it on the inside only:

```
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function(){
    var tot = 0;
    $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function(){
        tot += Number($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(tot);
    $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset tot to zero each time

```js
tot = 0;
$('input').change(function(){
  tot = 0;
  $("input").each(function(){
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise variable tot within change handler.

```
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function(){
  tot = 0;
  $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function(){
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(tot);
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `tot` variable inside `change` and declare it with variable keyword

```
$('form#lines-form-1 :input').change(function(){
var tot = 0;
  $("form#lines-form-1 :input").each(function(){
    tot += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(tot);
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/yq9zenaz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate solution:

What we do is get the jQuery collection of all inputs, use `.map()` to create a jQuery collection of input values, use `.get` to get the array from the jQuery object. After all of that we run `.reduce` with an add function on the array to get the sum of all values.

```js
var $inputs = $("form#lines-form-1 :input");

$inputs.change(function() {
  var tot = $inputs
    .map(function() {
      return Number(this.value);
    })
    .get()
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });

  console.log(tot);
  $('#tot-qty').text(tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="lines-form-1">
<input type="number" name="i1"><br>
<input type="number" name="i2"><br>
<input type="number" name="i3"><br>
<input type="number" name="i4"><br>
<input type="number" name="i5"><br>

</form>
<div id="tot-qty">0</div>
```

And if you *want* `tot` to be in the parent scope, you can move it's declaration to outside the `.change` event and it'll still work since it's being completely reassigned instead of added to.